# Tooltip, JQuery scrollbars not working in Ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, load, append, tooltip

I use `.append()` to load dynamic data in a page from another PHP page. The problem is the content from the another page have jquery scrollbars and tooltips. If I include jquery.js and remaining javascript code in that page the dynamically loaded content works well with the jquery scrollbars and tooltips but if I remove the jquery in that page it gets replaced with original windows scrollbar and tooltips. What is the solutions= for this?

Sample scrollbar code,

`$('div.box').scrollbars();// scrolbars`

PS: The reason I need to remove the script files from the second page is while using .load() or .append(), the host page freezes till the dynamic data loads completely.

Comment: do you call .scrollbars to the loaded content afterwards again?

Comment: @Alex: I tried that option using callback. But it makes the page freeze until the operation is complete.

Comment: Just initialize the scrollbars again when u load the content in your page. Dont call jquery and other js code instead put them in ur main page and then call scrollbars();

Comment: well then I assume something with your markup/ html is wrong, since how long can it take to apply scrollbars() ? usually this no big deal and this should not take long at all.
try to load the html without any js/ css and when finished loading, call .scrollbars() out of your original page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be really a bad practice too add script files again in the external file. Instead you have to add `$('div.box').scrollbars();// scrolbars` in the callback.

Example:

```
$("#samplediv").load('external_page.extension', function()  
{  
   $("#samplediv").scrollbars();  
});
```